# Changing file name and dates

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a macro that copies from a sheet and pastes to a destination sheet. The data sheet changes (we get a report each week) but the destination sheet is always the same. The two sheets can be saved in the same working folder.

The format of the name of the Excel sheet that is changing is

> XXX version_XXX XXXXXX XXXXX FY2022 XXXX WE 11-10-2021

The date on this file name is always the previous Monday which is when the report is run.

- I am thinking of using a text box, to input the new sheet name (data sheet). Is this the best way to do this or is there a more automated way.
- Considering the date is always the previous month is there a way to get the previous month and input into the macro? Note the date format below.
- Is there a way for the copy, paste to occur on the same sheet, i.e. copy paste over old data, instead of creating a new sheet as the macro below does.

This is what I have using record macro.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

'Macro1 Macro
Sheets. Add After:=ActiveSheet

Windows ("Report that is received data, date”).Activate
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches ("Slicer Month")
.SlicerItems ("1/09/2021").Selected = True
.Slicertems ("1/07/2021").Selected = False
.SlicerItems ("1/08/2021").Selected = False
.SlicerItems ("1/10/2021").Selected = False
(etc)
End With
With ActiveWorkbook. SlicerCaches ("Slicer_department")
.Sliceritems ("Category1").Selected = True
.Sliceritems(“Category2”). Selected = False.
.Sliceritems(“Category2”). Selected = False.
(etc)
End with
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches ("Slicer_manager")
.SlicerItems ("manager1").Selected = True
.Slicertems ("manager2").Selected = False
.SlicerItems ("manager3").Selected = False
(etc)
End with
range(“F22:M22”).select
selection.Copy 
Windows(“sheet where data is going”).Activate
Range(“A1”).Select
Activesheet.Paste
```

The above is repeated 3 times for the three separate lines to copy and paste.(A1, A2, A3).

Comment: Is it the 1st of the previous month you need?

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan thank you for your reply. Yes, I believe the format would be the same ie the first of the month.

Answer (score 0):

This will help with getting the start of last month within your code as well as selecting the last month in the slicer.  The way you had it, you would have to keep adding new months as they get added to your data.

In terms of the copy/paste, there are tons of posts on this and depends if you need to clear out the existing content.

```
Dim lastMonth As Date
Dim startLastMonth As Date
Dim startLastMonthSlicerTxt As String
Dim startLastMonthFileTxt As String
Dim fileName As String

' this would be the generic part of the file name without the date
fileName = "my file name "

' subtract a month from current date
lastMonth = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
' set the date to the 1st of last month
startLastMonth = DateSerial(Year(lastMonth), Month(lastMonth), 1)
' convert the date to text so you can use in slicer name
startLastMonthSlicerTxt = Format(startLastMonth, "d/mm/yyyy")
' convert the date to text so you can use in file name
startLastMonthFileTxt = Format(startLastMonth, "d-mm-yyyy")

' this appends the date and file extension to your generic file name
fileName = fileName & startLastMonthTxt & ".xlsx"
' as per your code, we now activate the Window but this time using the dynamic file name
Windows(filename).Active

' loop through the slicer items and only select if value matches last month
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Month")
    For Each si In .SlicerItems
        If si.Name = startLastMonthTxt Then
            si.Selected = True
        Else
            si.Selected = False
        End If
    Next si
End With
```

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan ! thank you for reponse where it says windows and activate sheet I need it to be a text box to place in the new name of the sheet XXX version_XXX XXXXXX XXXXX FY2022 XXXX WE 11-10-2021.so it changes every month. where it states Windows ("Report that is received data, date”)._// this should be a text box
Activate
  I also it need it to copy paste into the same sheet each time instead of creating a new sheet. The same copy paste occurs three times.

Comment: I'm guessing you have no VBA experience and you just recorded that macro as you asked if the file name could be automated and I gave you that in the code. The above method is much more "fool proof".  I have added one extra line.  As for the copy/paste, I mentioned there are lots of topics on this.  I can try to help with that, but you would need to add more information - ie what's different about the 2nd and 3rd time.

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan! thank you so much! how interesting. So the second copy paste takes the same but a different manager and the third copy paste takes the total of both the first and second manager. Just my query with the date is that the date for the slicer and the date on the file name will be different so im not sure how the above deals with that context. for example date for slicer is the 01/10/2021 but date for the file name might be 11/10/2021. That date is just when the report gets generated. So im just not sure how your code deals with the date of the file name.

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan! just an update the file name date is the previous Monday in the week. So the file name date will be the previous Monday.

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan! I hope your well. Are you able to assist with the above please.